# Double variable input

Tags: java, double, java.util.scanner

i'm currently learning java. I'm trying to make an example application that when we enter 4 number, the average of those number printed.

Here is my attempt:

```
package ave4numbers;

     import java.util.Scanner;

     public class Ave4Numbers {

          double a,b,c,d;
          double e = (a+b+c+d)/4;
          Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

          public static void main(String[] args) {

               System.out.println("Enter your numbers ");
               a = sc.nextDouble();
               b = sc.nextDouble();
               c = sc.nextDouble();
               d = sc.nextDouble();

               System.out.println(e);

          }

     }
```

But that doesn't work. what's wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: why is not working?? what are you getting?

Comment: The problem solved by AndyTurner and gonzo

Comment: @HaydarAlaidrus don't forget to mark the answer that helped resolve your question as **accepted**. You can also upvote the answer and any other answer that you find helpful/relevant.

Comment: @Raf Okay, did that. I cannot upvoting any answer yet since my reputation is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the error in trying to do the math before you have your numbers, you also need to declare your variables inside your `main` method or make your variables static.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a,b,c,d;  //These don't have to be static, if they are inside your method. 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your numbers ");
        a = sc.nextDouble();
        b = sc.nextDouble();
        c = sc.nextDouble();
        d = sc.nextDouble();
        double e = (a+b+c+d)/4;  //Do math after we save the numbers
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

or...

```
    static double a,b,c,d;  //If you leave these outside your method, it has to be static
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //This as well

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter your numbers ");
        a = sc.nextDouble();
        b = sc.nextDouble();
        c = sc.nextDouble();
        d = sc.nextDouble();
        double e = (a+b+c+d)/4; //Do math after we save the numbers
        System.out.println(e);

    }
```

Static Example

```
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //You can call static methods from another static method without an instance of the class. 
        //So you can do this if it is static. Notice I did not create an instance of Example. 
        Example.staticMethod();
        System.out.println(Example.staticVariable);
        //However these will NOT compile
        //Example.nonStaticMethod
        //System.out.println(Example.nonStaticVariable);

        //If you want access to the nonStaticMethod you need an instance. 
        Example myExample = new Example();
        myExample.nonStaticMethod();  //This WILL compile. 
        System.out.println(myExample.nonStaticVariable); //Will compile
    }
}

class Example{
    static String staticVariable = "";
    public String nonStaticVariable = "";
    public static void staticMethod(){
    }
    public void nonStaticMethod(){
    }
}
```

Comment: The locality of the variables has nothing to do with the problem here. It is changing two things, when only one is relevant. Your first answer is correct, the second one is unnecessary, and bad practice since the broader scope is not needed.

Comment: @AndyTurner you can not use non-static fields in a static method. OP will not be able to use variables `a-d` and `sc` in the `main` method if you do not make them static and leave them defined outside of the method.

Comment: But you simply don't need them declared outside the method. They are only used in one method, they should be local variables.

Comment: @AndyTurner I agree, hence why I put that method first in my solution. OP _does_ have them declared outside the method though. So you _do_ need them static if OP decides to leave them defined outside.

Comment: Very fundamental question: how this static works? im super new in programming @gonzo

Comment: hey @HaydarAlaidrus. I came up with a small example trying to explain static. Let me know if you have any additional questions or if you want me to explain it a bit better.

Comment: @HaydarAlaidrus the same thing applies to fields or variables as the example with methods. You need an instance to access non-static fields. So in your main you would need an instance of your `Ave4Numbers` class to access the fields you have without the `static` key word. Or just add `static` to the fields. Or delete the fields and create local variables inside the method.

Comment: ohh so in a nutshell 'static' is used if we declare a variable outside the method right? you enlighten me well,but give me further explanation please...:)

Comment: You can access `static` variables and methods from a `static` method without having an instance to the class.  You can access non-static variables and methods from a `static` method but you need to create an instance with the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize those variables or directly take them from input and then do the addition plus average in the print statement.

```
System.out.println((a+b+c+d)/4);
```

Modifying the code you should have something like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

              System.out.println("Enter your numbers ");
              double a = sc.nextDouble();
              double b = sc.nextDouble();
              double c = sc.nextDouble();
              double d = sc.nextDouble();

              System.out.println((a+b+c+d)/4);

        }
```

Comment: If you are doing math with variables, using `Double` creates unnecessary objects - use primitive `double`.

Comment: @AndyTurner can't believe I wrote Double instead of double. Definitely primitives. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

All this happens when the class is loaded. e will be 0, since a,b,c, and d are by default initialized to 0.

```
      double a,b,c,d;
      double e = (a+b+c+d)/4;
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Then below you have not changed the value of e in your main method, so it will still be 0

```
           System.out.println("Enter your numbers ");
           a = sc.nextDouble();
           b = sc.nextDouble();
           c = sc.nextDouble();
           d = sc.nextDouble();

           System.out.println(e);
```

To fix, do

```
           System.out.println("Enter your numbers ");
           a = sc.nextDouble();
           b = sc.nextDouble();
           c = sc.nextDouble();
           d = sc.nextDouble();

           //set the value of e
           e = (a+b+c+d)/4;

           System.out.println(e);
```

Comment: Not sure if I agree with your first statement. Local variables are not given a default value. Compile time error in line double e = (a+b+c+d)/4, can you please explain further, maybe I am misunderstanding and would love to know.

Comment: @Raf They're not local variables.

Comment: @AndyTurner you are a life saver, I knew I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

you tried to print the value of `e` before calculating accepting the values of a, b, c and d, do this instead

```
package ave4numbers;

 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Ave4Numbers {

      double a,b,c,d;
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

      public static void main(String[] args) {

           System.out.println("Enter your numbers ");
           a = sc.nextDouble();
           b = sc.nextDouble();
           c = sc.nextDouble();
           d = sc.nextDouble();

           System.out.println((a+b+c+d)/4);
      }
 }
```

Comment: But the error occurred on :
           a = sc.nextDouble();
           b = sc.nextDouble();
           c = sc.nextDouble();
           d = sc.nextDouble();
It's says, "Non-static variable a cannot be referenced from a static context on "a = sc.nextDouble();" and so on.

Comment: You'd need `a,b,c,d` and `sc` to be `static` - but you don't need non-local variables anyway.